# Are these WinMTR reports normal?

Tags: wireless-networking

Are these [WinMTR](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winmtr/) reports normal?

[Original Report](https://pastebin.com/CeGdbbeP)

[More Recent Report](https://pastebin.com/BizS8bcN)

I don't really understand Wi-Fi stuff but could someone please confirm that these numbers are normal?

I've contacted Cox support multiple times but each time they told me this is normal but I'm starting to find that a little suspicious since the numbers have only gotten bigger.

Comment: You say WIFI, but while you may connect to the router over WiFi (this part of your connection is fine) how are you connecting to your ISP? Cellular?  Whatever it is your connection to the ISP is not good.

Comment: What do you mean by that? like dsl?

Comment: Yes. Common connection types include ADSL,VDSL,cable,cellular, satellite. Basically what are you buying from your ISP?

Comment: I believe I'm paying for 1Mbps and dsl, but from what you've said it seems like there are issues with what I'm playing for

Comment: That may be. 1 megabit DSL is very slow and could be a (but by no means the only) factor. It could be any number  I'd suggest finding out from your ISP (a) What you are buying and (b) how much data you are using. If you add a comment with that we can start working out if the problem is on your network or your ISP. Random Seeming question - does your Internet cut out when your landline rings?

Comment: No my Internet works fine when my landline rings fine, maybe a small spike but nothing major

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They show a connection that is small and that is saturated. If that were my internet connection and I had not been advised of its limits upfront I would not be happy.

This problem could be caused by any combination if -

1. Your computers are sending a lot of data.
2. The providers connection is inadequate.
3. You have a very slow connection.
4. There is an issue in your router.

The packet loss and high latencies are coming in across your connection to the ISP. IMHO neither of those figures are acceptable unless you are purchasing less then a megabit and you are downloading heavily.